# Database design: Which rule requires database integrity with respect to two tables having the same attribute?

Tags: data-integrity

I am working with an RDBMS (mariadb) in which at least two tables (table1 and table2) share the same attribute, let it be "name".

"name" is the primary key in table1, and table2 is related to table1 by the following foreign key constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT `table2_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`name`) REFERENCES `table1` (`name`) ON DELETE SET NULL
```

The originator of the DB design and the associated source code decided to create a source code logic which finally leads to several records in table2 which have "name" to be NULL. Although technically obviously possible, this violates, from my point of view, the database integrity.

In discussions with the team members I could point to this fact, but to learn more about database design and to possibly have even stronger arguments, I would like to put this particlar integrity requirement down to one of these "famous" rules one reads about in database design text books (e.g., Codd's 12 rules, Normalization, ...). I am not database designer enough to pinpoint this safely. But I am quite sure some of the experts here can do this easily.